# Window partition by aggregation count

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to do a count over a window. The count result of the aggregation should be stored in a new column:

Input dataframe:

```
    val df = Seq(("N1", "M1","1"),("N1", "M1","2"),("N1", "M2","3")).toDF("NetworkID", "Station","value")

    +---------+-------+-----+
    |NetworkID|Station|value|
    +---------+-------+-----+
    |       N1|     M1|    1|
    |       N1|     M1|    2|
    |       N1|     M2|    3|
    +---------+-------+-----+

    val w = Window.partitionBy(df("NetworkID"))
```

The result that I have so far:

```
        df.withColumn("count", count("Station").over(w)).show()
        +---------+-------+-----+-----+
        |NetworkID|Station|value|count|
        +---------+-------+-----+-----+
        |       N1|     M2|    3|    3|
        |       N1|     M1|    1|    3|
        |       N1|     M1|    2|    3|
        +---------+-------+-----+-----+
```

The result I would like to have :

```
+---------+-------+-----+-----+

|NetworkID|Station|value|count|

+---------+-------+-----+-----+

|       N1|     M2|    3|    2|

|       N1|     M1|    1|    2|

|       N1|     M1|    2|    2|

+---------+-------+-----+-----+
```

Because the count of stations for the NetworkID N1 is equal to 2 (M1 and M2).

I know I can do it by creating a new dataframe, select the 2 columns NetworkID and Station and do a groupBy and join with the first.

But I have a lot of aggregate count to do on different columns on my dataframe and I have to avoid joins.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You need your partitionBy on "Station" column as well because you are counting Stations for each NetworkID.

```
scala> val df = Seq(("N1", "M1","1"),("N1", "M1","2"),("N1", "M2","3"),("N2", "M1", "4"), ("N2", "M2", "2")).toDF("NetworkID", "Station", "value")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [NetworkID: string, Station: string ... 1 more field]

scala> val w = Window.partitionBy("NetworkID", "Station")
w: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec@5b481d77

scala> df.withColumn("count", count("Station").over(w)).show()
+---------+-------+-----+-----+
|NetworkID|Station|value|count|
+---------+-------+-----+-----+
|       N2|     M2|    2|    1|
|       N1|     M2|    3|    1|
|       N2|     M1|    4|    1|
|       N1|     M1|    1|    2|
|       N1|     M1|    2|    2|
+---------+-------+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is distinct count of "Station" column, which could be expressed as `countDistinct("Station")` rather than `count("Station")`. Unfortunately, it is not supported yet(only in my spark???).

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Distinct window functions are not supported
```

As a tweak, you can use both `dense_rank` forward and backward.

```
df.withColumn("count", (dense_rank() over w.orderBy(asc("Station"))) + (dense_rank() over w.orderBy(desc("Station"))) - 1).show()

+---------+-------+-----+-----+
|NetworkID|Station|value|count|
+---------+-------+-----+-----+
|       N1|     M1|    2|    2|
|       N1|     M1|    1|    2|
|       N1|     M2|    3|    2|
+---------+-------+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its late, but try this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val result = df
  .withColumn("dr", dense_rank().over(Window.partitionBy("NetworkID").orderBy("Station")))
  .withColumn("count", max("dr").over(Window.partitionBy("NetworkID")))
```